# Get avg hours of a day by weeks and month

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am stuck on this and I have no idea how to do that.

I have this table

```
create table events(event_datetime datetime,event_code varchar(40),val varchar(40));

insert into events (event_datetime, event_code, val) 
    values ('2018-01-01 06:00:00', '50', '1'),
           ('2018-01-01 07:00:00', '54', null),
           ('2018-01-01 11:00:00', '50', '2'),
           ('2018-01-01 13:00:00', '54', null),
           ('2018-01-02 07:00:00', '50', '1'),
           ('2018-01-02 23:00:00', '54', null),
           ('2018-01-24 07:00:00', '50', '1'),
           ('2018-01-25 23:00:00', '54', null),
           ('2018-02-02 10:00:00', '50', '1'),
           ('2018-02-02 12:00:00', '54',null)
```

Event_code 50 means the event starts. Event_code 54 means the event stops.

I want to sum the hours between 54 and 50 for a day (sometimes there are more than one 50-54 a day)
Than I want to do the AVG of days for 1 week, four times.

For example with the data above for Week 1 :

```
2018-01-01 07:00:00 - 2018-01-01 06:00:00 = 1hour  
2018-01-01 13:00:00 - 2018-01-01 11:00:00 = 2hours  
2018-01-02 23:00:00 - 2018-01-02 07:00:00 = 16hours  
Day 1 = 3hours  
Day 2 = 16hours  
Day 3-7 = 0hours  
Week 1 = AVG(days) = 19/7
```

The output would be something like :

```
| Month   | Week 1     | Week 2     |  Week 3     |  Week 4    |
|---------|------------|------------|-------------|------------|
|     Jan |avghours/day|avghours/day|avghours/day |avghours/day|
|     Feb |avghours/day|avghours/day|avghours/day |avghours/day|
```

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c095f8/4)

EDIT :
events 50 are always directly followed by a 54.
events never last more than a day.

**EDIT 2 :**

I created a stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE tablediff()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done int default false;

    DECLARE v_day DATETIME;
    DECLARE v_code VARCHAR(40);

    DECLARE v_day_1 DATETIME;
    DECLARE v_code_1 VARCHAR(40);

    DECLARE start_time DATETIME;
    DECLARE stop_time DATETIME;
    DECLARE code VARCHAR(40);

    DECLARE duration TIME;

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT event_datetime, event_code as code, event_param_1
        FROM events
        AND event_code =50
        ORDER BY event_datetime ASC;
    DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT event_datetime, event_code as code, event_param_1
        FROM events
        AND event_code = 50
        ORDER BY event_datetime ASC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    OPEN cur1;
    OPEN cur2;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
    (
        start_time DATETIME;
        stop_time DATETIME;
        code VARCHAR(40);                       
        duration TIME;
    );
    FETCH cur2 INTO v_day_1, v_code_1;
    forLoop: LOOP

        FETCH cur1 INTO v_day, v_code;
        FETCH cur2 INTO v_day_1, v_code_1;
        CASE 
            WHEN  v_code = 50 THEN 
                IF v_code_1 = 54 THEN
                    SET start_time = v_day;
                    SET stop_time = v_day_1;
                    SET code = v_code;
                    SET duration = duration + TIMEDIFF(stop_time, start_time);
                ELSE 
                    SET start_time = null;
                    SET stop_time = null;
                    SET code = null;
                    SET duration = duration;
                END IF;
        END CASE;

        INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (start_time, stop_time, code, duration);

        IF done
            THEN
                LEAVE forLoop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
    CLOSE cur2;
END#
```

It works to show the start and stop hours even if there is a no 54, but I need to work on the time calculation, the duration time doesn't work yet, it shows null at each row.

Comment: And what if the events span a week boundary?

Comment: Is the order of events assured? Does it always start with 50 which is always followed by exactly one 54? Does ist always end with 54?

Comment: A month is 28 to 31 days, so week #4 is 7 to 10 days and the other weeks are exactly 7 days?

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber Yes the order is assured and it ends with a 54.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Do you mean a 50 active on a day that ends on another day ? If yes, then it is not possible it always end before the day change

Comment: @Zorkolot Yes the weeks last seven days. If there is more than seven days at week 4, which will be the case most of the time, than week 4 shoud be bigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ID field (as the key) and event identification field after the code would be ideal.

If that is not possible, a function will help you out:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION event_stoptime (start_time datetime)
RETURNS datetime
BEGIN
    DECLARE stop_time datetime;
    SET stop_time = (SELECT MIN(event_datetime) FROM events WHERE 
event_datetime > start_time);
    RETURN stop_time;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Once the function is built, you can combine it with MySQL date functions to get the data you need:

```
SELECT  event_datetime as event_start, 
        event_stoptime(event_datetime) as event_stop, 
        TIMEDIFF(event_stoptime(event_datetime), event_datetime) as event_duration,
        WEEK(event_datetime) as event_week,
        MONTH(event_datetime) as event_month
from events 
where event_code = 50;
```

The results should I got were

```
| event_start        | event_stop          | duration  | week| month|
'2018-01-01 06:00:00', '2018-01-01 07:00:00', '01:00:00', '0', '1'
'2018-01-01 11:00:00', '2018-01-01 13:00:00', '02:00:00', '0', '1'
'2018-01-02 07:00:00', '2018-01-02 23:00:00', '16:00:00', '0', '1'
'2018-01-24 07:00:00', '2018-01-25 23:00:00', '40:00:00', '3', '1'
'2018-02-02 10:00:00', '2018-02-02 12:00:00', '02:00:00', '4', '2'
```

GREAT BIG CAVEAT: If there is no corresponding 54 event for a given 50 (due to error, etc.), the times will be heavily skewed.

**Here is a better solution** using an ID field. I included the ID in the insert statement for ease of testing:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`event_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`event_code` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`val` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`event_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO `events` 
    VALUES  (1,'2018-01-01 06:00:00','50','1',NULL),
            (2,'2018-01-01 07:00:00','54',NULL,1),
            (3,'2018-01-01 11:00:00','50','2',NULL),
            (4,'2018-01-01 13:00:00','54',NULL,3),
            (5,'2018-01-01 09:00:00','50',NULL,NULL),
            (6,'2018-01-02 23:00:00','54',NULL,5),
            (7,'2018-01-24 07:00:00','50','1',NULL),
            (8,'2018-01-25 23:00:00','54','3',7),
            (9,'2018-02-02 10:00:00','50','1',NULL),
            (10,'2018-02-02 12:00:00','54',NULL,9),
            (11,'2018-01-30 23:00:00','54','3',NULL);
```

The view joins the table to itself to pick the correct "54" to "50". Note the creation of the date to find the first week of the month:

```
CREATE VIEW `event_list` AS 
select  `events`.`ID` AS `ID`,`events`.`event_datetime` AS `event_start`,
        `end_events`.`event_datetime` AS `event_stop`,
        timediff(`end_events`.`event_datetime`,`events`.`event_datetime`) AS `event_duration`,
        week(`events`.`event_datetime`) AS `event_week`,
        month(`events`.`event_datetime`) AS `month_number`,
        monthname(`events`.`event_datetime`) AS `event_month`,
        WEEK(STR_TO_DATE(concat(year(events.event_datetime), '-', month(events.event_datetime), '-', '01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) as first_week
from (`events` left join `events` `end_events` on((`events`.`ID` = `end_events`.`event_id`))) 
where (`events`.`event_code` = '50');
```

The select statement uses IFs to select the right data for week summaries. The times are broken into seconds for calculating duration, then reassembled for display;

```
select  event_month,
        sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(if(event_week = first_week, event_duration, 0)))) as week_one,
        sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(if(event_week = first_week + 1, event_duration, 0)))) as week_two,
        sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(if(event_week = first_week + 2, event_duration, 0)))) as week_three,
        sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(if(event_week = first_week + 3, event_duration, 0)))) as week_four,
        sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(if(event_week = first_week + 4, event_duration, 0)))) as week_five
from    event_list
group by event_month
order by month_number
```

Inelegant, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a great start and it gives me the duration by interval of start and stop. I have some questions, why do you select the week(event_datetime) and month(event_datime), what valuable information does it give? Is it normal that I get 12 for each row with month(event_datetime)? Why don't you specify that only if the next row is a 54 than you set the stop time to avoid screwed times in case of error?

Comment: Week and Month are [MySQL Date Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that return the week of the year and the month for a given date. This will help you calculate the averages you specified.

Comment: It is possible to modify the function, though you would be better served by modifying the table structure. An ID field for the primary key is almost always recommended when creating tables, and a field to store the event identification with the ending event_time will simplify matching start to end times.